# Parse HTML (without HTML semantics being followed) using Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I have an HTML document containing data:

```
<div>
    <p class="someclass">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</div>
```

while parsing I use:

```
div_node.children.each do |child|
  if child.node_name == 'p'
    #store it as html string in db
    store(child.to_html)
  end
end
```

When I check the database, I get only the outer `<p>` tag:

```
<p class="someclass">
</p>
```

No inner `<ul>` tag content is stored or retrieved.

I know that the `<p>` tag cannot contain the `<ul>` tag but the document we got from the client has the data and there are about 1000 documents with the data so I cannot edit them manually

Comment: @Pete again to convert p tag to div i'll have to use nokogiri where there will be no content inside the p tag node and so would the converted div tag. 


thoughts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using `Nokogiri::XML` parser for parsing the `HTML` doc

I had to change my script at numerous places

**Parsing code**

```
@xml_doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(file) { |cfg| cfg.noblanks }
@xml_doc.remove_namespaces!
```

**Changes Done**

- change `attribute` method to `attr`
- chaining `attr` with `text` method is not needed here
- need to check about the invalid HTML5 tags though
- some more parsing logic changes were needed
- `node.to_html` works like a charm here so i was able to store complete HTML in db

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `Nokogiri::XML` parser instead of the `Nokogiri::HTML` one. It shouldn't care about the tag semantics, but I'm not sure how will it handle those parts of HTML5 which are not valid XML.

Comment: Exactly i'll have to change whole script of thousands of lines :( if i try to parse it as xml

Comment: Invalid HTML gets fixed-up and flagged in `errors`. Invalid HTML5 tags aren't important in XML unless they are syntactically wrong, in which case they'll also be fixed-up and flagged. XML doesn't give special meaning to a tag like HTML does, so it should only care that tags are nested and closed properly.